# flex&bison parse quoted string

Tags: c, flex-lexer, string-literals

I'm writing a parser in pure C with flex&bison. I'm trying to figure out how to parse C-like string literals enclosed in double quotes. Could somebody provide me with a simple flex code snippet to do this?

For instance, in ANTLR grammar for string literals could be expressed in just those two lines

```
StringLiteral: UnterminatedStringLiteral '"';
UnterminatedStringLiteral: '"' (~["\\\r\n] | '\\' (. | EOF))*;
```

It seems that in flex it's much more difficult to achieve.

Comment: Literals are scanned by the scanner, not parsed by the parser. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple flex solution would look a lot like the Antlr rules you provided:

```
string_start    ["]([^"\\\r\n]|\\(.|\n))*
%%
{string_start}["]   { /* Do something with yytext */; return STRING; }
{string_start}      { /* Register unterminated string error */ }
```

(There are some details missing here, like whether or not newlines can appear in a string. It looks to me from the Antlr pattern like you expect the answer to be "no", so I edited my original to conform better.)